# SQL group by function to categorize only the most recent data

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this table called title where it stores all of the title held by each employee which will look like this

| emp_no | title | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Engineer | 2019-01-01 |
| 101 | Senior Engineer | 2020-02-01 |
| 102 | Engineer | 2019-01-11 |
| 102 | Senior Engineer | 2020-02-11 |
| 103 | Engineer | 2019-01-21 |
| 104 | Engineer | 2019-01-31 |
| 105 | Associate | 2019-01-01 |
| 106 | Associate | 2019-01-11 |
| 106 | Manager | 2020-02-11 |
| 107 | Associate | 2019-01-21 |
| 107 | Manager | 2020-02-21 |
| 108 | Associate | 2019-01-31 |

Notice that each employee can have more than 1 title. For example emp 101 title is engineer in 1st January 2019 but got promoted as senior engineer one year later.

Now lets say i want to count how many employees for each position. I have tried using the count function along with group by (to group the number of employee by the title) but the problem is, the SQL query also count the past position of every employee.

To be exact, I only want to include the most recent role that an employee currently has. So in this case, the result I am expecting is
Engineer: 2 employees (because the other 2 has been promotod to senior engineer),
Senior engineer: 2 employees,
Associate: 2 employees (because the other 2 has been promotod to manager),
Manager: 2 employees

Is there some kind of way to achieve that?
NOTE: this table format is from one of the SQL online course that i'm taking so I'm not the one who make the table. and also in the original table in containes tens of thousands of data.

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. Only tag the one you are *really* using.

Comment: Most RDBMSes support `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` nowdays https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/row_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
select title, count(*) as Count
  from your_table t
 where not exists 
       (select 1 from your_table tt
         where tt.emp_no = t.emp_no and tt.start_date> t.start_date)
group by title
```

Comment: Hi, so the table name is 'titles' so I should replace your_table with titles right? and what about the 'tt' ant 't'? should i replace them with 'titles' also? because when i do so, the SQL still counting all of the previous title from the employee that has been promoted

Comment: Oh nevermind, i tried only replacing the 'your_tables' with my table name and leave the 'tt' and 't'. IT WORKS THANK YOU. but what is the function of 'tt' and 't'? is it just somekind of aliases or nickname that you give?

Comment: Yes, You are right. It is called the alias.

Comment: You can consider accepting one of the answers as correct answer so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the data in where condition while counting. Query as follows:

```
select title, count(distinct emp_no) as Count
from (select emp_np, title, max(start_date) as start_date
      from table 
      group by emp_np, title) subset
group by title
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the answer, but when i tried to run the query, sql goes error saying "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to rename the inner table. I have edited the query. Should work now!

Answer (score 0):

```
select title,COUNT(*) numberOfEmp from 
(
  select distinct emp_no
  ,(select top  1 title from [dbo].[Tbl_title] a where  a.emp_no=m.emp_no
  order by [start_date] desc
  ) title
  from [dbo].[Tbl_title] m
) mTable
group by title
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: My bad, im using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend a correlated subquery, but for a very particular reason:

```
select title, count(*)
from t
where t.start_date = (select max(t2.start_date)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.emp_no = t.emp_no
                     );
```

The particular reason for suggesting this is that it is easy to modify this for the number of employees "as of" a particular date.  For instance, if you want the number of employees as of 2019-01-01, you change the `where` to:

```
where t2.emp_no = t.emp_no and t2.start_date <= '2019-01-01'
```

Comment: Ah I see, this adds some kind of versatility into it. Yes, I guess it's kind of important when I want to apply a date filter. It works too, Thanks mate! Cheers!